# Xamarin Native linking failed Paypal

Tags: ios, paypal, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm using https://github.com/Rodolfocartas/PayPalMobileXamarinBindings to integrate Paypal in my app.
On simulator it works, but on real device, Xamarin Studio builds with follow error

Error MT5211: Native linking failed, undefined Objective-C class: PayPalFields. The symbol 'OBJC_CLASS$_PayPalFields' could not be found in any of the libraries or frameworks linked with your application. (MT5211)

I'm using Unified API so i can't use --registrar:legacy mtouch arguments.

How i can fix?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

Could be a linking error.

Go on your iOS project settings and change the linker options to "Don't link".

[image: Linker Settings in iOS]
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/linker/

Answer (score 1):

I've added [Protocol] on PayPalFields and now it works.
Thank you